# I cannot open a Partition of a Harddrive when Shared

Tags: finder, hard-drive, partition

I've partitioned 0.75TB of external harddrive space for photo backups, which is shared on the network with a PC. However when shared I am unable to open the folder in Finder, as it will hang for 2 seconds and crash - even when nobody is accessing it.

I've tried using a different filesystem, but none seem to avail. I seem to be able to access it on the PC just fine.

The full external harddisk is 2 TB, split into:

- 1TB - Extra Storage
- 0.75TB - "Photos"
- 0.25TB - Time Machine Backup (I tried accessing the folder while and after the backup was running)

Any help would be appreciated.

(Edit: I should note that I can access the folder via other methods (the "select a folder" screen and Terminal, for example))

Console log: http://hastebin.com/oyakuxepoj.vala

Comment: did it ever work, (before), could you share the operating systems!

Comment: It hasn't ever worked. This is the first time @Buscar웃

Comment: does any of this works for you http://www.howtogeek.com/189250/how-to-share-files-between-mac-os-x-and-windows-with-boot-camp/

Comment: It should be a viewable partition - however Finder *crashes* when I open that partition. I've even tried using a FAT32, which is compatible with both Windows and OSX. @Buscar웃

Comment: ok, show us the console log at the time stamp of crash, some 20 lines total.

Comment: @Buscar웃 , to be safe instead of sorry heres everything that was there when it crashed (I placed a marker, and then crashed the program) http://hastebin.com/oyakuxepoj.vala

Comment: ok reading :( so you use wunderlist, did you try without it?

Comment: @Buscar웃 uninstalled it, this error still happens: http://hastebin.com/wowijiwulu.vala

Comment: It shows the TBannerControllerView to be the problem. Try in Safe mode please.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've tried loading it in safe mode however it won't let me load the partition (I could be doing something wrong though)

Comment: look in to this report on your mac for more information /Users/fdwalmsley/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-12-25-180312_Ffaens-MacBook-Pro.crash

Comment: @Buscar웃 heres the report: http://hastebin.com/etewexakib.pl ... I'm not really sure what to look for in it...